# wifi is very slow, card RT5390

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I've brand new ASUS X501A and Ubuntu 12.04 (and i'm bad in Ubuntu) and the WiFi is extremely slow - 1Mb/s. WiFi chip is RT5390.

I tried everything i found in the net, so i need step by step instructions.

```
pabris@OrientExpress-Ernests:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: a4:17:31:50:11:66
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.5.0-23-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 08:60:6e:99:fd:a4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.2 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: You say you tried everything on the net. Please describe what you tried exactly. People here probably can't read your mind...

Comment: For example these 3 steps: http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/

Comment: first i install Ubuntu 12.10, than upgrade to 13.04,than install 12.04 LTS over. I found manufacturers driver here http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01_windows.php?sn=501 , but i have no idea how to install it manually

Answer (score 2):

I also have an ASUS X501A and I had the same problem with the wireless being slow.

I followed the instructions from this post:
[Not Able to get wifi working under 13.04 (Ralink rt5390)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302)

Basically you do the following (taken from above post):

1. Enter your name and email and download driver at: [http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downl...il.php?sn=5001](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5001)
2. Go to the download directory and run these commands

   ```
   tar -xvf 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.bz2.bz2
   cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
   wget http://gridlox.net/diff/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
   patch -p1 <rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
   ```

   If patch asks for directory point it to pci_main_dev.c
3. Make sure ./os/linux/config.mk reads HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
4. Build and install the driver:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe rt5390sta
   ```

   I got various compiler warnings and an error message at the end of the `make` command saying I didn't have enough permissions but it worked after the `sudo make install`.
5. Blacklist the concflicting kernel modules so run

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

   And then at the end of the file, add these lines:

   ```
   # Blacklist conflicting kernel modules
   blacklist rt2800pci
   blacklist rt2800lib
   blacklist rt2x00usb
   blacklist rt2x00pci
   blacklist rt2x00lib
   blacklist rt2860sta
   blacklist rt3090st
   ```
6. Reboot and it should now have faster wireless. I had to re-enter my wireless password but it worked great.

Comment: If you get a compile error on `current_fsgid()` change it to `current_fsgid().val`